# Is there a way to optimise an OR check where one calculation is much simpler than the other?

Tags: c++

I have an OR evaluation as part of an if. In both cases, the "if" code will run if either of the OR evaluations are true. However, one of these calculations is a very simple math check, and the other involves looking up data from an external file and takes significantly longer.

Are there C++ compilers that will intelligently order these operations and skip the other or are they always both evaluated? If they don't, does anyone have a suggestion for something neater than a nested if to skip the file check? I guess I was ideally hoping that with a left to right evaluation and knowing it's a pure OR function I could ideally order the OR so that the fastest checks were on the left with a smart enough compiler.

```
if(a==b || a==file_lookup(file_address,px_address))
{
   operation
}
```

versus

```
if(a==b){func_operation;}
else if(a==file_lookup){func_operation;}
```

Comment: (built in) `||` does already skip evaluation of the second operand when the first is true

Comment: Yes, and it's called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: I am genuinely curios, what documentation for `||` did you read that did not mention it? (try here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

Comment: The MOST common case is that `a == b`  and `a==file_lookup(file_address,px_address)` both give a result of numeric/pointer type (e.g.  both comparisons produce a `bool`) and, for that, the `||` ALWAYS behaves like you describe.  In the VERY RARE case where that assumption is not true AND there is an overloaded `operator||()` function in play  (e.g.  `if(a==b || a==file_lookup(file_address,px_address))` is treated by the compiler as `if (operator||(a==b, a==file_lookup(file_address,px_address)))`  then both arguments will be evaluated before being passed to a function named `operator||()`.

Comment: The order in which the two sides of `||` are evaluate is well-defined. The compiler is not allowed to choose an order. Therefore, if you, the programmer, know an order that looks "better" than the other, you should place the subexpressions in that order.